# Can categorical information improve prediction for out-of-sample categories?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, random-forest

Suppose we have records with several features relating to a target number that we're trying to predict. All records follow the same general underlying pattern, and are learned quite well by a `RandomForestRegressor`. Let's now say that all records have added a categorical feature, which can be encoded as additional information to improve upon the model's prediction ability. So far, so good.

But *now* let's say we want to use our regressor that was *trained on the data including the categorical feature* to predict records with new *categories not represented in the training data*. In this context, does the categorical information become useless (or worse?) Should the model be retrained without categorical information available in order to get the best generalization performance (since it's been previously fit to categories not in this dataset)? Or, is there some possible way that knowing category membership in the training data could improve prediction ability for out-of-sample categories?

Comment: "all records belong to one of several groups, which can be encoded as additional information" : so what do you predict ? if you try to predict the groups and give the groups as feature for your training set there is no learning actually, it is just a projection on that feature and therefore the prediction of unseen data would be impossible ...

Comment: I'm trying to predict a target value that is separate from the categorical feature I called a group. I'll rephrase to clarify.

Comment: So for example, the training data has a variable "country" with values `[US, Canada]` and in the test data the country variable takes values `[Mexico, Cuba]`? If these sets have no intersection, then you shouldn't include the variable. If you expect to see **some** of the original values in the test data, then you should use it.

Comment: @maxymoo Some of the test data will have intersection with the countries, and some won't (let's say 50% won't). To get the best performance on the data without intersecting countries, perhaps a separate model should be trained that ignores this dimension altogether.

Comment: na just include it

Comment: You should take into account all possible values of the variable. If you get unknown value in the current object then assign it to a *special* value for unknown constants. In this case your cat. column becomes useful. However the more possible constants you know the better model you build.

Comment: Also notice: the algorithm of random forest commonly does not overfit. Your forest consists of random trees additional information doesn't do it worse. However it could be very small improvement. To check it use component analysis algorithm, may be some other features (or the cat. feature) are not valuable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these sets have no intersection, then you shouldn't include the variable. If you expect to see some of the original values in the test data, then you should use it.